# How many time I send data using ajax to zend controller

Tags: zend-framework

I try to send data using ajax to zend controller second time but I got server error.

This is ajax to send data

```
$("input[name=emailmarket]:radio").change(function(){
    var enable = $(this).val();
    if(enable == 1){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/customer/market",
            type: "POST",
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: {data:enable},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("fail :(");
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

This is controller function

```
public function marketAction(){
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if ($this->_request->getPost('data')) {
            echo "this is enabled"; 
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: You probabaly don't have a view script or a context enabled for processing the action

Answer (score 1):

We need to close requested data of ajax what I means

```
public function marketAction(){
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if ($this->_request->getPost('data')) {
            echo "this is enabled";
            exit;
        }        
    }
}
```

You can see I used exit at the end of requested data